# Is there any good programming way to Save/store/keep Page data(Variables)

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I am developing an iOS application.

I am loading Page Views, and many page Views.

After loading that either I can go for Change settings, for this app, and Sign in and many more actions I can do.

(So, whenever I load many page views, after that I can change the settings as I told.)

(Now, whenever I left/navigate the PageViewsController to another View Controller to change settings, fine,)

And After that whenever I am coming back again by using Pop View to PageViewsController, right ..

"Here the PageViews are loaded again." but I want to keep the state of the PageViews.

Like - Which was the last page I opened. Which was the last activity I have done on PageViews.

So, How can I preserve the activity of this view controller in a good/constructive/proper/best/easy/**simplified** way.

So.

I should Load the PageViews and By keeping the changes to some variables and after loading page views I just need to apply the settings.

Please ask me if any confusion, or to simplify. I am ready to edit/ explore the question. To find out the answer.

I have to keep track these many of variables each time.

```
 self.TotalAdvertisements=0;
            self.pageCurlModel.apiPageNo=0;

            //    isHeaderRequired=YES;
            isAPICallStarted=NO;

            firstTimeToThisPage=YES;

            isErrorOnAdvertisement=NO;

            [self hideAllViewsExceptHeaderView];


            NSLog(@"location.city.Name %@",location.city.Name);
            NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");




    //TODO: MAnage PAssed Location Cycle.
    NSLog(@"passedAdvertisementCategory %@",passedAdvertisementCategory);

    /*If you are coming from category view controller than you must have object selected subcategory
     */

//    case NORMALUSER:
//    //NIL means ALL.

//    isHeaderRequired=YES;
//    [self unLoadPageCurlViews];


    [self ApiCallForAdvertisementCategoryId:categoryId andAPIPageNo:self.pageCurlModel.apiPageNo andUserId:userId];
```

The big problem is to manage this bool variables. I hate these bool vars. Do you have any solution to replace any construct to replace this BOOL variables.

Comment: You need a model, A structured data store that holds you objects. Have a look at Apple's [core data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for this, or if you don't care are about the data persisting you could create a singleton data manager that gets destroyed each time the app closes.

Comment: Right I thought to create one class to have all bool vars to store in it. Have a shared manager class. And I can maintain iit's class by methods. But I think I have to ask this question in more good way, and more detailing. SO could understand more easily, and somebody can help me effectively.